# Not showing complete image

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-scrollview

I have a `ImageView` which shows image whose size is 2000*650. I am not able to show this complete image on screen. I also have `HorizontalScrollView` as a parent of imageview.

But i am able to show this complete image which is scrollable in xhdpi. I have different resolution for hdpi as well as xhdpi. xhdpi has image of more resolution.

Comment: have you tried android:scaleType ?

Comment: @JackKFouani : yes i have used it to fitXY